# jQuery Validation Plugin: same form, different validation submitHandler

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using a single form in two different scenarios - Create and Edit.

I do something like

```
<?php
if($status == 'new')
    echo '<button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="btn">Submit!</button>';
else
    echo '<button id="btnEdit" type="submit" class="btn">Edit!</button>';
?>
```

What I want to achieve on my javascript end is to validate the form and call the correct web service according to which button is pressed. I am using the jQuery Validation Plugin found [here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate).

**Javascript**

```
$('#myForm').validate({
    submitHandler: function(data) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "service1.php"
        ...... other AJAX stuff ..........
      });
    }
}

$('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
    // call service1.php
});

$('#btnEdit').click(function() {
    // call service2.php
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Marikkani's suggestion, I have implemented the below and it works. Hope it helps someone with a similar problem using Javascript and PHP.

In my form file I used a hidden div to store the `type (new or edit)`.
`<input type="hidden" id="type" value="<?php echo $type; ?>" />`

Thereafter, in my javascript file I retrieve this value and check before calling the respective ajax.

```
$('#resForm').validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var type = $('#type').val();

        if(type == 'new') {
            $.ajax({
                url: "service1.php"
                .... other AJAX stuff
            });
        } else { // type is edit
            $.ajax({
                url: "service2.php"
                .... other AJAX stuff
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The method for validate can be a single function and you can set a flag(For example you will get an id in the edit page) to identify edit page or add page. So that you can check the flag in submit handler and submit the form to where it needs to be submitted. I'm not familiar with PHP and i hope this might help you.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I am trying to find the flag you mentioned from the jQuery Validation Plugin website but I cant seem to locate it. Are you able to point me to that part of the documentation?

Comment: This is the code i have in one of my application. Its in ColdFusion. **<cfif val(url.location_id)>var isEditpage = 1;<cfelse>var isEditpage = 0;</cfif>**

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction! I have an answer now! :)